# Subversion - problem creating a new repository

Tags: svn

I have recently taken over a linux box running subversion.

The folder where the the repos look like they are installed is in: `/home/svn`

In this folder I see a folder named `web_projects` and in that folder I see `conf` `dev` `db` etc etc

I am trying to add a new repository to this server, but I'm getting the following error:

`svnadmin: '/home/svn/web_projects/my_project' is a subdirectoy of an existing repository rooted at '/home/svn/web_projects'

Does anyone know why I can't seem to add a new repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that /home/svn/web_projects is (the top level of) an existing repository, and will not let you create one inside that. You need to create yours at /home/svn/my_project.

Comment: Ok, but If I use tortoiseSVN, I browse to: `http://svnaddress/svn/web_projects`, I see a bunch of repositories..

Comment: I have no idea what TortoiseSVN might do or say, as I have never used it. I am interpreting the error message that you got.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you used the "top level" directory as a svn repository, so now you can't have two repositories because one is nested in another project's directory.

Structure your `/home/svn` area like so `/home/svn/project1` `/home/svn/project2` `/home/svn/project3` ...  with multiple svnadmin create commands like

```
svnadmin create /home/svn/projectN
```

Since you can't nest one repository into another, to start you will have to move your svn files from /home/svn to /home/svn/project1

Comment: Ok, but If I use tortoiseSVN, I browse to: `http://svnaddress/svn/web_projects`, I see a bunch of repositories..

Comment: You made web_projects a SVN project, not a directory containing multiple SVN projects.  The same idea applies, if you want multiple projects under a directory, it needs to be a directory only, not a project, so move web_projects to web_projects/project1 and svnadmin create webprojects/project2 (and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Because /home/svn/web_projects/ is already a repository (as explained by the tool).

You cannot create a repository inside this folder. You can however do that just next to this one:

```
svnadmin create /home/svn/other_project
```

hth :)