# Create SVN repository from svnadmin hotcopy

Tags: linux, svn

I have a backup of all my svn repository folders and sadly I didn´t know anything of the svn dump format. The backups are created with "hotcopy"

Now my server is broken and I had to reinstall everything from scratch and I want to reimport the svn repositories.

Copying them into the folder didn´t work and

> svnadmin create /my/existing/repository

didn´t work too.

Is there any possibility to restore my repositories in an "easy" way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `svnadmin create` *is* the easy way. I'd try to figure out what's going wrong with that.

Comment: When I do that on an existing repo, I´m getting: svnadmin: E165002: '/home/pi/svn/myrepo' is an existing repository

Comment: So it sounds like your svn server may still be limping along? Not sure entirely what all has happened, but take a peak at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638340/subversion-problem-creating-a-new-repository).

Comment: it´s a fresh server with no created repositories and I want to use the repositories from my old server?!The repositories are not in the .dump format, they are simply a copy of what svn creates in the file system after creating a repository with svnadmin create

Comment: Probably you'll want to strip the `.svn` entries out of them before importing to the new server.

Comment: I think you don´t understand my problem. I don´t have those projects anymore, I just have a copy of the repository data from the server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just transfer the hotcopy to the new server and point the svn server at it.

The only thing to watch out for is a large difference between the versions of the svn server. If the new server isn't compatible with the format used on the old server it might not work.

Here's what I have done as an experiment to illustrate. I have a repository on my laptop `~/svnServe/importantApp`

## Start up the svn server against the original repo

```
svnserve --listen-host 127.0.0.1 -d -r ~/svnServe/importantApp/
```

## Run a list command from the svn client

```
svn list svn://127.0.0.1/
branches/
tags/
trunk/
```

## Make a hot copy of the server

```
svnadmin hotcopy ~/svnServe/importantApp ~/svnServe/importantAppHotcopy
```

## Start the server against the hotcopy

```
sudo svnserve --listen-host 127.0.0.1 -d -r ~/svnServe/importantAppHotcopy/
```

## Run a list command from the svn client

```
svn list svn://127.0.0.1/
branches/
tags/
trunk/
```

Comment: thank you, and how can I point the svn server to it? Because that´s exactly where I stuck

Comment: What are you using as the server, Ubuntu, Windows, Apache?

Comment: its a raspberry pi with raspbian. Thank you very much, I´m going to try it out

Comment: okay, just a simple svnserve -d -r ./svn did it for me :) thank you very very much. But what happens if the server restarts?

Comment: There's probably a way to hook it into init.d so you don't have to run `svnserve` by hand. I'm unfamiliar w/ raspberry pi, is it ubuntu?

Comment: nope, it´s raspbian. But maybe if I do it like you said, 1. creating a repo, then copying the old stuff, then linking it does that by default as it has also a created repo in the same folder...trying...

Comment: You could also try [svn+ssh](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~crf/crf-guide/resources/software/svn-ssh.html).